# why do we divide by 1024 for a custom LRUCache in android

Tags: android, caching, byte

```
final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
```

AND

```
final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 8);
```

Howcome i have to divide the maxMemory by 1024. Furthermore, why would one divide again by 8. I've seen it done both ways in the tutorials i've seen for writing a custom LRUCache yet i don't understand the implications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Howcome i have to divide the maxMemory by 1024

You do not have to divide anything by anything to use `LRUCache`.

What you *do* need is for the `maxSize` that you pass into the `LRUCache` constructor to be in the same units as you use in your `sizeOf()` method.

For example, here is a sample bit of `LRUCache` code, taken from [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html):

```
int cacheSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4MiB
LruCache<String, Bitmap> bitmapCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getByteCount();
    }
}
```

Here, the unit of size is a byte. So, the comment indicates that they are passing in a number of bytes representing 4MiB, and `sizeOf()` returns the size of the `Bitmap` in bytes.

Comment: Howcome we use MiB's for the cache size? Why not just bytes?

Comment: @3alto: The sample from the JavaDocs -- which I posted in my answer -- uses bytes.

Comment: I can't really wrap my head around this for some reason lol. Really what is confusing me, is Runtime#maxMemory() returns us the amount of memory we have in bytes, yes? Then how can dividing the number of bytes by 1024 give us the measurement in kilobytes?

Comment: @3alto: "Then how can dividing the number of bytes by 1024 give us the measurement in kilobytes?" -- um, that is how you calculate kilobytes. 1 kilobyte is 1024 bytes. So, to convert N bytes into kilobytes, you divide by 1024.

Comment: THAT'S WHAT I THOUGHT. I used a byte converter to be sure, but it said 1024 bytes equals 1.024 kilobytes, and 1 kibibyte lol. so i was confused. Thanks for helping me figure this out man =)